# method() from other apex class in to VF page

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, visualforce, salesforce-service-cloud

Can we use method() from other apex classes into the VF page directly and by not using the controller of that VF page?

In Java, we can use package and do so, but I have no idea what to do with the apex and Vf page.

I would be thankful if anyone with the knowledge can help me out with this doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `method()` from another controller on your visualforce page, if `method()` is part of a global class.
See [Apex Class Definition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_defining.htm) and [When to use public, private, global](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000QurFQAS)